# SQL Server string concat issue for SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was trying to concatenate values by comma when I will use group by. So I use `STUFF()` function and `for xml path('')` clause. Here is my script

```
IF EXISTS 
( 
 SELECT * 
 FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects 
 WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#tmp1') 
) 
BEGIN 
 DROP TABLE #tmp1 
END 

create table #tmp1
(ID  varchar(2),CName varchar(20) )

insert into #tmp1(ID,CName) values ('A','BBA Reman')
insert into #tmp1(ID,CName) values ('B','BBA Reman')
insert into #tmp1(ID,CName) values ('C','CT Tech')
insert into #tmp1(ID,CName) values ('D','CT Tech')

select
t1.CName,
stuff((
    select ',' + t.ID
    from #tmp1 t
    where t.CName = t1.CName
    order by t.ID
    for xml path('')
),1,1,'') as ConCatStr
from #tmp1 t1
group by t1.CName
```

The above script run successfully in SQL Server 2005 but not running in SQL Server 2000. So tell me how to restructure my script as a result it should run in SQL Server 2000 also.

Comment: FOR XML PATH is SQL 2005 onwards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a lot of methods to create the comma separated list without using xml, take a look at the following:

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/